# Interpolate position 5 minutes after starting from point A to B

Tags: r, r-sf, r-sp, osrm

below is an example of finding route, travel time and travel distance from 'One World Trade Center, NYC' to 'Madison Square Park, NYC' using `osrm` package in R. (I learnt it from  [Road Routing in R](https://www.jla-data.net/eng/routing-in-r-context/)). The travel time here is 10.37 minutes.

Q. How can I interpolate and find location after 5 minutes.

[image]

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tidygeocoder)
library(osrm)

# 1. One World Trade Center, NYC
# 2. Madison Square Park, NYC
adresses <- c("285 Fulton St, New York, NY 10007", 
            "11 Madison Ave, New York, NY 10010")

# geocode the two addresses & transform to {sf} data structure
data <- tidygeocoder::geo(adresses, method = "osm") %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)

osroute <- osrm::osrmRoute(loc = data,
                           returnclass = "sf")

summary(osroute)



library(leaflet)

leaflet(data = data) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
  addMarkers(label = ~address) %>% 
  addPolylines(data = osroute,
               label = "OSRM engine",
               color = "red")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `osrm::osrmIsochrone()` function to find the five minute travel distance polygon, and then find the point that the route intersects the polygon.

It looks like its on Clarkson Street between Hudson & Varick.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tidygeocoder)
library(osrm)

# 1. One World Trade Center, NYC
# 2. Madison Square Park, NYC
adresses <- c("285 Fulton St, New York, NY 10007", 
              "11 Madison Ave, New York, NY 10010")

# geocode the two addresses & transform to {sf} data structure
data <- tidygeocoder::geo(adresses, method = "osm") %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)

# get route from 285 fulton to 11 madison
osroute <- osrmRoute(src = data[1,], dst = data[2,], returnclass = 'sf')

# five minute isochrone from 285 fulton
five_min_isochrone <- osrmIsochrone(data[1,], breaks = 5, returnclass = 'sf')

# isochrone has to be cast to MULTILINESTRING to find intersection as a point
intersection <- five_min_isochrone %>% 
                  st_cast('MULTILINESTRING') %>%
                  st_intersection(osroute)


library(leaflet)

leaflet(data = data) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
  addMarkers(label = ~address) %>% 
  addPolylines(data = osroute,
               label = "OSRM engine",
               color = "red") %>%
  addPolygons(data = five_min_isochrone) %>%
  addMarkers(data = intersection, 
             label = '5 minute distance')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @mrhellmann.  But I have more than 20,000 trips and it would be very costly to create isochrones for each trip. Is there efficient way to do it.

Comment: You could use `st_sample(x, type = 'regular')` to sample points on the linestring, and then find the point that is closest to 5 mins/total trip minutes along the line (In this case it would be about halfway along the line).  This would assume a constant speed for the trip though.